# remove characters begin and end of string

Tags: javascript, jscript

I have $45.00 as string and need to get 45 out of that.
following is working...
How do I write this in one line?

```
var x= "$45.00" ,cents =/\.00$/;
var z= x.replace(/^\$/,'');
z = z.replace(cents,'');
```

Comment: You want *only* the '45'? What happens if the price is `"$45.05"`?

Comment: Why do you need it all in one line?

Comment: If you just want the "dollar" amount, you could use `parseInt(x.replace(/^\$/, ''), 10)`

Comment: david T..your question make sense. and my code does that and what needed to compress it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the `.replace()` calls can be daisy-chained, with the second one acting on the results of the first:

```
var x = "$45.00", cents = /\.00$/, z = x.replace(/^\$/, '').replace(cents, '');
```

Comment: While this is essentially what the OP asked for, this one line of code is much harder to read than the original 3 lines.

Comment: var x= "$45.05" ,doller =/^\$/, cents =/\.00$/;
var z= x.replace(doller,'').replace(cents,''); works fine and clean

Answer (score 0):

If the question is that straight forward you can simply use this one line to get the left of the dot value.

```
var x= "$45.00".split('$')[1].split('.')[0];
```

**Explanation:**

1. You assign the variable x to the price string in this case
   "$45.00"
2. Then use the string function split, to divide the string into two
   arrays.
3. Right now you have ["$"] in position zero and the rest in position 1
   ["45.00"]
4. You then use the same function on the second array at position one
   to divide at the dot character.
5. Now you have at position zero ["45"] and position 1 [".00"]
6. You need position 0 so that's the index you you will use and that's
   it.

I think it's pretty straightforward but tried to be as through as possible.